# print a students grade with hours python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

In my program, if I change

```
stud1 = Student("John","Brown",["A","B","A"],["15.0","25.0","20.0"])
```

to

```
stud1 = Student("John","Brown",[],[])
```

Whats a good way to print out grades selected for a student with its the hours spent.
Right now the output for "print (stud1.getGrade())" is ('A', '15.0').

Code:

```
class Student(object):
def __init__(self, name, surname, grade, hours):
    self.name = name
    self.surname = surname
    self.grade = grade
    self.hours = hours

def getName(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.name)

def getSurname(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.surname)

def getGrade(self):
    #return '{} {}'.format(self.grade, self.hours)
    for a,b in zip(self.grade, self.hours):
        return (a,b)

def getHours(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.hours)

def getQPoints(self):
    pass
stud1 = Student("John","Brown",["A","B","A"],["15.0","25.0","20.0"])
stud2 = Student("Mary","Watson","B","20")

print (stud1.getName())
print (stud1.getSurname())
print (stud2.getName())
print (stud2.getSurname())
print (stud1.getGrade())
print (stud1.getHours())
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the output formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def getGrade(self):
    for a,b in zip(self.grade, self.hours):
        return (a,b)
```

Should be

```
def getGrade(self):
    return zip(self.grade, self.hours)
```

Comment: I tried that and ended up getting <zip object at 0x03A5C3C8>

Comment: @Ibrahim Thats odd, I'm running Python 3.6 and the print statement gives me `[('A', '15.0'), ('B', '25.0'), ('A', '20.0')]`